# macOS Catalina /bin/sh vs /bin/bash and showing history with preceding hash

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, sh, macos-catalina

Not really a question but an observation. When I do sys ad on Linux, I like to precede commands with a hash '#' to proof-read what I am about execute, and also to leave a breadcrumb so that I can come back to it later on.

I've found out recently on macOS Catalina (this being my main workhorse now), that `bash` does not print lines in the history file with a preceding hash, that doe snot appear to be the case in othe flavours of Linux, i.e. RHEL, Ubuntu

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo foo
foo
$ #echo bar
$ !:p
echo foo
```

```
$ echo $SHELL 
/bin/sh
$ echo foo
foo
$ #echo bar
$ !:p
#echo bar
```

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15
BuildVersion:   19A602
```

Outputs of `$HISTIGNORE` `$HISTCONTROL`

Sure

```
$ echo 0e"$SHELL\n$HISTIGNORE\n$HISTCONTROL"
/bin/sh
```

```
$ echo -e "$SHELL\n$HISTIGNORE\n$HISTCONTROL"
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `echo $HISTCONTROL` and `echo $HISTIGNORE`?

Comment: Hi @Spiff sure, I've editted my post with the output

Comment: macOS ships a really old version of bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just want to answer my question

@egmont you're right bash is shipped with a really old version

My solution was to upgrade bash.

This post in Medium clearly explains how to upgrade bash on MacOS, and is exactly what I did to get commands preceded with `#` to be printed in my history again

https://itnext.io/upgrading-bash-on-macos-7138bd1066ba

I'll post setps to upgrae bash in MacOS with Homebrew

```
$ brew install bash 
$ sudo echo /usr/local/bin/bash >> /etc/shells 
$ sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash # for the current user
```

Here are some tests before and after upgrading bash

Before upgrading bash

```
$ echo foo
foo
$ #echo bar
$ !:p
echo foo
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

After upgrading bash

```
$ echo foo 
foo
$ #echo bar
$ !:p
#echo bar
$ bash--version
-bash: bash--version: command not found
Geralds-MacBook-Pro:~ gerald$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be unique to Catalina.  I have not upgraded yet.

```
$ echo 

$ # hello 
$ !:p 
# hello  
$
```

I use this "feature" as well so it would be useful to find a way to sort that.

For completeness:

```
$ echo \"$HISTIGNORE\" 
""
$ echo \"$HISTCONTROL\" 
""
```